# Why is translational energy part of the equation for kinetic energy for the first leg of a double pendulum?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Isn't all kinetic energy of the first leg already in the rotational energy based on the angular velocity theta_1_dot?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum#Lagrangian

(i'm referring to 1/2*m*(v1)^2)

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says that "The first term is the linear kinetic energy of the center of mass of the bodies and the second term is the rotational kinetic energy around the center of mass of each rod." This means that your statement would be true if all the mass of each rod was concentrated at its geometric centre, but it is not.  So the computation  is the same as for any rigid body: the total KE is the sum of $1/2 M_{\rm tot} v^2_{\rm CofM}$ and the rotational KE about the centre of mass computed as if the C of M was at rest.

Comment: I don't get it, the rods don't rotate around their center of mass. They rotate around the end point where they are attached....so then there is no rotational kinetic energy around the center of mass...there is rotational energy around the rod its end point and that is why I don't see why you need an additional kinetic energy term...get my confusion?

Comment: @graaf   You need to read up on the theorems about kinetic energy, It doesn't matter where they rotate about.  In any kind of motion whatsoever, the total KE is sum of the rotation KE about the C of M and the KE of the body as if all the mass was located at the C of M. This is discussed at the beginning of all books on mechanics.  It's just an application of Pythagoras' theorem combined with the definition of the C Of M. I suspect  you are are thinking of the parallel axis theorem. If $I$ were the moment of inertia about the rotation point then you would only need the rotation term. It is not.